# c++ type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, type-mismatch

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class people{
    public:
    virtual void insert(T item)=0;
    virtual T show(T info)=0;
};

template<class T>
class name
{
    private:
     T fname;
     T lname;
     public:
      name(T first, T last);
    //  bool operator== (name & p1, name &p2)
};
template <class T>
name<T>::name(T first, T last){
    fname = first;
    lname = last;
}
template <class T>
class person : public people<T>
{
    private:
    T a[1];
    int size;
    public:
    person();
    virtual void insert(T info);
    virtual T show();
};
template<class T>
person<T>::person(){
    size = 0;
}
template<class T>
void person<T>::insert(T info){
    a[0] =info;
}
template<class T>
T person<T>::show(){
      return a[0];
 }
int main(){
    string first("Julia"), last("Robert");
    name<string> temp(first,last);
    people<name>* aPerson = new person();
    aPerson-> insert(temp);
    aPerson->show();
    return 0;
}
```

These are the errors I keep getting and I can't pinpoint what really is the problem:

```
test.cpp:52: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class T> class people'
test.cpp:52: error:   expected a type, got 'name'
test.cpp:52: error: invalid type in declaration before '=' token
test.cpp:52: error: expected type-specifier before 'person'
test.cpp:52: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'person'
test.cpp:53: error: request for member 'insert' in '* aPerson', which is of non-class type 'int'
test.cpp:54: error: request for member 'show' in '* aPerson', which is of non-class type 'int'
```

Comment: Off-topic, but you should get out of the habit of using `new` when you don't need it, and of using dumb pointers when you do need it. Otherwise, you'll end up spending your life debugging memory leaks like the one in your example, rather than writing interesting code.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I am here to learn. If I would forego using new, could you please provide some alternative way of doing it?

Comment: In this case, a simple automatic local variable: `people<name<string>> aPerson;` When you do need dynamic allocation (because the object has to outlive the function that creates it), you should learn about [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and, in particular, *smart pointers*.

Comment: @MikeSeymour If I'm going to use people<name<string>> aPerson; will aPerson have an array of type name?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the code properly. You'd need `aPerson` to be the concrete type `person`, not the abstract `people`. There's still no need for `new` though.

Answer (score 16):

`name` is a templated class, so you must specify the template:

```
people<name<string>>* aPerson = new person<name<string>>();
```

Comment: @user2972206 You're welcome! It would help everybody else as well if you mark this question as `resolved`.

Comment: This code would end up with compiler error: '>>' should be '> >' within a nested template argument list

Comment: @John_West `>>` is supported [https://stackoverflow.com/q/6695261/1969455](from C++11 on).

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl No evidence for this beyond the link.

Comment: @John_West [N3337](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n3337.pdf) 14.2.3: _[..] Similarly, the first non-nested >> is treated as two consecutive but distinct > tokens, [..]_