# no matching function call to a constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class people{
    public:
    virtual void insert(T item)=0;
    virtual T show()=0;
};

class name
{
    private:
     string fname;
     string lname;
     public:
      name(string first, string last);
    //  bool operator== (name & p1, name &p2)
};

name::name(string first, string last){
    fname = first;
    lname = last;
}
template <class T>
class person : public people<T>
{
    private:
    T a[1];
    int size;
    public:
    person();
    virtual void insert(T info);
    virtual T show();
};
template<class T>
person<T>::person(){
    size = 0;
}
template<class T>
void person<T>::insert(T info){
    a[0] =info;
}
template <class T>
T person<T>::show(){
      return a[0];
}
int main(){
    string first("Julia"), last("Robert");
    name temp(first,last);
    people<name>* aPerson = new person<name>();
    aPerson-> insert(temp);
    cout << aPerson->show() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':

test.cpp:53: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << people<T>::show [with T = name]()'

test.cpp: In constructor 'person<T>::person() [with T = name]':

test.cpp:51:   instantiated from here

test.cpp:37: error: no matching function for call to 'name::name()'
test.cpp:21: note: candidates are: name::name(std::string, std::string)
test.cpp:12: note:                 name::name(const name&)
```

Comment: You have no appropriate default constructor for class `name` obviously! Just read what the compiler tells you ...

Comment: You should get a good tutorial on [c++-metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming), instead of getting through [question wise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877896/c-type-value-mismatch-at-argument-1-in-template-parameter-list) here ...

Comment: By the way, you should include the `<string>` header explicitly. There's no guarantee that [`<iostream>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream) will include [`<string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string).

Answer (score 2):

`name` doesn't have a default constructor, therefore you cannot initialize it with `new person<name>`. The easiest way to solve this problem is to add a default constructor for `name`:

```
name() { }; //add this to name under public: of course
```

Problem 2: you did not overload the `<<` operator in name:
Here is a basic example:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const name &nm); //Inside name class
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const name &nm){ //OUTSIDE of name
    stream << nm.fname << " " << nm.lname << std::endl;
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: the next problem is, there is no appropriate `operator<<` that accepts a `name` on the right hand side.

Comment: @user2972206 the problem is: you haven't got one for your name class.

Comment: new error: 'std::ostream& name::operator<<(std::ostream&, const name&)' must take exactly one argument