# "<varName> was not declared in this scope" using templates and inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, compiler-errors

I'm working with PCL (Point Cloud Library). I've made a class (`myPCL_SI`) that inherits from a PCL template class (`pcl::SpinImageEstimation`). I've created an other normal class (`myPCL`) that creates a `myPCL_SI` object.

I do this because I need to access to a protected method from `pcl::SpinIMageEstimation`. If someone knows a better solution, please say me.

Ok, my problem is that when I try to create a `myPCL_SI` object, the compiler give me this error:

```
error: ‘spinImage’ was not declared in this scope
error: template argument 1 is invalid
error: template argument 3 is invalid
```

My code is this one:

**myPCL class (only my method)**

```
void myPCL::calcSpinImage(){

    myPCL_SI<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal, pcl::Histogram<153>> spinImage;

    // doing more things...
}
```

**myPCL_SI class (header)**

```
#ifndef MYPCL_SI_H
#define MYPCL_SI_H

// a lot of includes...

using namespace pcl;

template <typename PointInT, typename PointNT, typename PointOutT>
class myPCL_SI : public SpinImageEstimation<PointInT, PointNT, PointOutT>
{
public:
    myPCL_SI();
    void compute(PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud);

};

#include "mypcl_si.cpp"

#endif // MYPCL_SI_H
```

**myPCL_SI class (impl)**

```
template <typename PointInT, typename PointNT, typename PointOutT>
myPCL_SI<PointInT, PointNT, PointOutT>::myPCL_SI()
{

}
```

Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an older compiler, you need a space between the two `>>` after `153`.

See [Template within template: why "`>>' should be `> >' within a nested template argument list"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695261/template-within-template-why-should-be-within-a-nested-template-arg)

Comment: I spend 2 hours with this problem and is this f***g typo. I will go to cry :'(. Thanks a lot! :D:D and sorry for ask this question, but I didn't found anything about it. Thaanks!!!!