# C++ Vector compile error on template struct

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
template<class T>
struct TSData{
    int timestamp;
    T data;
}; 

int main () {
    std::vector<TSData<int>> Gen;   //Compile Error
    std::vector<TSData<int> > Stts; //Compiles fine
}
```

I'm using Visual c++ 6.0, and I ran into this issue today. I'm wondering why having a space makes the second statement OK. Without the space I would get the following errors:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'Stts' 
error C2654: 'OLPkrStts' : attempt to access member outside a member function
error C2143: syntax error : missing '>' before ';'
```

Comment: `>>` is valid only since C++11

Comment: @EdgarRokyan, that has been valid for a long time, VS C++ 6.0 is a bit old. That's all.

Comment: So it's just a nuance of an old C++ compiler then? And they would both compile with a newer compiler?

Comment: maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695261/template-within-template-why-should-be-within-a-nested-template-arg

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Also, unless you have to use Visual c++ 6.0 I would suggest you use MSVS 2017 which is C++11/14(mostly) and some 17 complaint

Comment: If you have the option, you can download the community editions of the latest VS tools from MS for free. I would strongly advise using them instead of using VS C++ 6.0.