# C++ header file with stack variable

Tags: c++, stack, header-files

I recently started learning C++.

I would like to know why it is not possible to define a variable in a header file like this :

```
#ifndef DUMMY_H
#define DUMMY_H


class Dummy
{
stack<std::pair<int, int>> s;   

};


#endif //DUMMY_H
```

Comment: To use `stack`, the compiler must know `stack` exists. `#include <stack>`

Comment: and BTW - thats not defining a variable. Its defining a class. Quite a different thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing:

- a `#include <stack>` statement, so the compiler knows what `stack` is (and a `#include <utility>` statement for `std::pair`).
- a `using namespace std;` or `using std::stack;` statement, so you can use `std::stack` without specifying the `std::` prefix.

Try this:

```
#ifndef DUMMY_H
#define DUMMY_H

#include <stack>
#include <utility>

using std::stack;

class Dummy
{
    stack<std::pair<int, int>> s;   
};

#endif //DUMMY_H
```

You really shouldn't use a `using` statement in a header file <sup>*</sup>, unless it is nested inside of an explicit namespace:

```
#ifndef DUMMY_H
#define DUMMY_H

#include <stack>
#include <utility>

class Dummy
{
    std::stack<std::pair<int, int>> s;   
};

#endif //DUMMY_H
```

<sup>* `using` a type/namespace into the global namespace can cause undesirable side effects if you are not careful!</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You must include required header before using them.
Also precaution has to be taken care to add appropriate namespace resolution.

```
#ifndef DUMMY_H
#define DUMMY_H

#include <stack>
#include <utility>  // This has added for pair

class Dummy
{
    std::stack<std::pair<int, int> > s;  // Notice the space between > >.
};

#endif //DUMMY_H
```

Additional space is required in earlier version of C++98 for grammatical reason.
More information: [Template within template: why "`>>' should be `> >' within a nested template argument list"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695261/template-within-template-why-should-be-within-a-nested-template-arg)

This is not required from C++03