# Declaration error when defining a boost library lock free queue in c++

Tags: c++, boost, lock-free

I am new to c++ and I am trying to create a lock free queue in c++98 using the boost library (version 1.53). When I compile my code in c++98 I get the following error:

```
error: ‘q’ was not declared in this scope
  boost::lockfree::queue<T *, boost::lockfree::capacity<SIZE>> q;
```

When I remove the capacity option (boost::lockfree::capacity) the error appears to disappear. What am I missing here and doing wrong?

The line that causes the error exists by itself within the constructor and is as follows:

```
    boost::lockfree::queue<T *, boost::lockfree::capacity<SIZE>> q;
```

Comment: The minimum required compiler is Visual Studio 2008 (VC++ 9.0) SP1 or another C++11 compliant.

Comment: please show a [mre] and include compiler name and version and compile options. Might just need a space in `>>` so that it's not mistaken for shift right

Comment: @AlanBirtles adding spaces appears to have fixed the error thank you.

Comment: Yeah. Before C++11, `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` would interpret the final `>>` as operator. You need spaces to separate them. I suppose there is a duplicate somewhere, but I cannot find it.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: I found [Template within template: why "\`>>' should be \`> >' within a nested template argument list"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6695261) with google for `site:stackoverflow.com nested template ">>"`.  That Q&A is so old it doesn't mention C++11, though!  Ah, [For nested templates, when did \`>>\` become standard C++ (instead of \`> >\`)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7087033) is more recent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before C++11, `<<` or `>>` in any place (including templates argument list) would be interpreted as operator. You need to separate every bracket with a space:

```
boost::lockfree::queue<T *, boost::lockfree::capacity<SIZE> > q;
```

With C++11 or later, your original line should compile as-is.